# EF Core Many to Many Relationship Querying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, ef-core-2.0

Hello i must filtering the many to many tables. example;

```
public class LanguageSchool
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<LanguageSchoolLanguageSchoolProgram> LanguageSchoolLanguageSchoolPrograms { get; set; }
}

public class LanguageSchoolProgram
{
     public long Id { get; set; }
     public virtual List<LanguageSchoolLanguageSchoolProgram> LanguageSchoolLanguageSchoolPrograms { get; set; }
}
public class LanguageSchoolLanguageSchoolProgram
{
    public long LanguageSchoolProgramId { get; set; }
    public virtual LanguageSchoolProgram LanguageSchoolProgram { get; set; }
    public long LanguageSchoolId { get; set; }
    public virtual LanguageSchool LanguageSchool { get; set; }
}
```

and query;

```
List<long> selectedLanguageEducationIds = [1,2,4,6]
foreach (var education in langEducations)
{
    var list = context.LanguageSchools
        .Where(x => x.LanguageSchoolLanguageEducations
            .Contains(new LanguageSchoolLanguageEducation() { 
                LanguageEducation = education, 
                LanguageSchool = x, 
                LanguageEducationId = education.Id,
                LanguageSchoolId = x.Id 
            })
        ).ToList();
}
```

but this codes not working. my question is how i can search/filtering/querying many to many properties.

Comment: Your question is not clear! Please tell me what output you are excepting from the query? More importantly i didn't find any relation of `LanguageSchoolLanguageEducations` to the models you provided!

Comment: I suggest taht you could share complete code of model and query to us.Besides,EF core uses [Eagerly loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data) to load related entities as part of the query by using Include methods.You could combine include method with `Where` statement to do the filter.